# ¿Cómo cambiar la forma de acceder a mi cuenta de Stack Overflow?

Tags: soporte, faq, login

Actualmente ingreso a [Stack Overflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) a través de Facebook, pero lo que quisiera es cambiar el modo de acceso a mi cuenta actual y que ahora sea a través de un correo electrónico y contraseña, esto con motivo de que en mi actual trabajo está restringido [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/)

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

Comment: Propongo esta entrada como traducción de [How do I change my OpenID provider(s)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/793/) y [How do I remove an OpenID or login?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22223/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Opción 1. Añadir las credenciales de otro Open ID.

Como se explica en [la ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials), para agregar un nuevo Open ID, dentro de tu perfil, selecciona "Edición de perfil y configuración" y luego [Mis Inicios de Sesión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/me).

[image: Mis Inicios de Sesión + añadir más inicios de sesión]

Que te llevará a poder elegir el Open ID para agregar en tu cuenta:

[image: Selección de Open ID]

---

#### Opción 2. Añadir a StackExchange OpenID como proveedor de credenciales.

En https://openid.stackexchange.com podés crear tus credenciales de SE OpenID.

[image: Completar datos personales]

Una vez que hayas confirmado el mail, podrás iniciar sesión en https://openid.stackexchange.com y seleccionar "Use your own URL to login".

[image: Click en use your own URL to login]

De donde podrás copiar la última URL (con el GUID).

[image: copiar la última URL]

Que se puede utilizar dentro de "[Mis Inicios de Sesión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/me)" para agregar un Open ID al igual que en la opción 1.

[image: Agregar la URL como nueva credencial]

Esta opción puede tardar un tiempo en algunos casos que pase por un proceso de aprobación manual (generalmente con reputación alta o diferentes cuentas de mail).